# apache location directive not matched due rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache

My main goal is to override a php.ini setting through apache config for only one url.

I am using the Location directive to do so. But there are a bunch of other rewrite rules that always change the location to index.php(which I cannot change) 
for e.g. the following works

```
<Location "/">
    ..some php settings...
</Location>
```

But, the following does not work

```
<Location "/foo/bar">
    ..some php settings...
</Location>
```

because each time the location rewrites to "index.php" (through other configs)

I want my setting to work only for http://www.myurl.com/foo/bar.
What can I use to match my url & override the php value ?

Comment: Please add the configuration in your question you're using right now.

Comment: use 'if': `<If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ /^(?:GET|POST)\ \/foo\/bar/"> ... </If>`

Comment: Thanks Deadooshka .. Unfortunately <If> commands works only for apache > 2.3 . Is there any other solution ?